# Inspect from a specific range of an array

Tags: java, android

I have got a String array:

String[] s={"one","two","three","four"};

Now I want to inspect from first three items of that array and do not want the inspection to include the fourth item.
I am using the following code to inspect:

boolean b = Arrays.asList(s).contains("two");

Wondering if there is a solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
String[] newArray=new String[3];
//Copy the first three elements into newArray
System.arraycopy(s,0,newArray,0,3);
```

Comment: I am not trying to create new array. Anyways thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit I figured a solution out without the need of creating new array:

```
 int INSPECTION_LENGTH=3;
String query="two";

public static boolean b(String[] s,int length,String query){
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
if(s[i].equals(query)){
return true;
}
}

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Make a sub-list of `List`

If using a `List` such as `ArrayList` rather than a simple array, you can [produce a sub-list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)) that is based on the original but masks away unwanted elements.

Make a `List` from your array.

```
List < String > allStrings = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( array ) ) ;
```

Of, if you want a non-modifiable list, use `List.of`.

```
List < String > allStrings = List.of( array ) ;
```

Get your sub-list, calling `List::subList`. We must use annoying zero-based index counting. The first number is inclusively the start. The second number is exclusively the end. So getting elements 1, 2, and 3 but not 4 and more translates as `( 0 , 3 )`. I might be tempted to write this as `( 1 - 1 , 4 - 1 )` meaning “ordinal one inclusive to four exclusive, subtracting one for index counting”.

```
List< String > firstThreeStrings = allStrings.subList( 0 , 3 ) ;  // Using annoying zero-based index counting. First number is inclusive while the second is exclusive.
```

Be aware that any changes to the original `List` will show through to the sub-list. We have not created a copy, we have a created second view onto the first list’s content, hiding unwanted elements.